# Can't not connect cassandra DB on GCP(google cloud)

Tags: node.js, cassandra, google-cloud-platform, firewall

I using GCP and want to connect cassandra from outside.
Already add firewall on GCP

`cassandra-rule  Apply to all    IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0 tcp:9042, tcp:9160 
Allow 1000  default`

I can using the following code change to 127.0.0.1 and query perfectly.
But if I run this code outside and connect to the GCP 35.190.233.64  it will cause

```
{ [Error: All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, 35.190.233.64:9042: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 35.190.233.64:9042. See innerErrors.]
```

the code

```
   var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
    var client = new cassandra.Client({ contactPoints: ['35.190.233.64'], keyspace: 'tutorialspoint' });

client.execute("select * from emp", function (err, result) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(result)
    } else {
        console.log(err)
        console.log("No results");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, as you want to listen from that IP address for client connections,  you must specify the `rpc_address` on the cassandra.yaml file:

See [cassandra.yaml configuration doc](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html#configCassandra_yaml__rpc_address) for more info.

Comment: Thanks,can I also set only for query not for update and delete?Or some acl?

Comment: You must configure it at server level. About ACL, you can look into role-based ACL: https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/role-based-access-control-in-cassandra